# Can't redirect all output of program

Tags: bash, redirect

I am attempting to redirect all output of a program (Steam) to /dev/null so it doesn't show up in the terminal.

Here's what I've tried:
`steam & > /dev/null 2>/dev/null` and `steam & > /dev/null 2>&1`

Neither of which suppress it's messages whatsoever (as far as I can tell.)

My understanding is that & detaches the process from the terminal, and > redirects input/output, with the default/blank > being stdout and 2> being stderr. Are there more outputs than those two? Why am I still seeing output if I'm redirecting all of it away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
steam 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

`2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout, and `> /dev/null` redirects stdout to `/dev/null`.

The `&` to background the process was misplaced. It must go at the end of the line. If placed after `steam` but before `>`, nothing from `steam` will be redirected, though the process will properly background.

Comment: Can you explain why this should work?

Comment: @Seth: `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdin, and `> /dev/null` redirects stdin to `/dev/null`.

Comment: That works perfectly. My best guess as to what I was doing wrong was redirecting the output of the "&" command, since it was placed right after the command (as opposed to at the end, which backgrounds it and redirects properly.)

Comment: @Adobe You should edit that into your question :)

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue with `steam` happens to be a special-case which can sometimes require some special understanding and handling.  The `steam` runtime is a wrapper script containing the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# default to minimize on close, so we never have a running steam process
# in the background because of a broken Tray Icon on some desktops/WMs
#export STEAM_FRAME_FORCE_CLOSE=${STEAM_FRAME_FORCE_CLOSE:-0}
exec /usr/lib/steam/steam "$@"
```

Note that it uses the `exec` shell built-in, as well as passing all arguments with `$@`.

So, while the usual solution for shell output redirection would be similar to [@Adobe & @Gary's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/274299/19264), this particular type of case can often require a bit more nuanced approach and understanding of what is going on behind the scenes.  There is some subtlety as to why all possible output redirection methods and order of operations for `steam` can sometimes not work as expected.

## The `exec` shell Built-In (first nuance)

The POSIX standard defines a behavior for [the `exec` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/exec.html).  Bash provides this via the [`exec` Shell Built-In](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec).  Which can affect standard IO redirection, and the sub-process tree, depending on how it's called.  **Note:** While this didn't technically apply in the OP's specific use-case and listed commands, I'm including it here because it's a common pitfall and caveat to be aware of.

From the IEEE Std. 1003.1, 2004 Edition:

> The exec utility shall open, close, and/or copy file descriptors as specified by any redirections as part of the command.
>
> If exec is specified without command or arguments, and any file descriptors with numbers greater than 2 are opened with associated redirection statements, it is unspecified whether those file descriptors remain open when the shell invokes another utility. Scripts concerned that child shells could misuse open file descriptors can always close them explicitly, as shown in one of the following examples.
>
> **If exec is specified with command, it shall replace the shell with command without creating a new process. If arguments are specified, they shall be arguments to command. Redirection affects the current shell execution environment.**

The `exec /usr/lib/steam/steam "$@"` line in the `/usr/bin/steam` wrapper script will replace the executing `/bin/bash` shell (as per the "shebang line) without creating a new sub-process.  The `$@` argument specifier is passed with double quotes, which should in most cases avoid any side-effects with IO redirection operators.  However, it's good to be aware that passing in some output redirection operators as arguments (e.g. via errant quotes `"` or `'` or via `eval` with escape char `\`) could present the opportunity to inject shell redirection operators into the script such that the `exec` call would possibly affect the standard IO & file descriptors of the command.  So, depending on how you're passing `2>&1`, `>somefile` or other redirection operators to the wrapper script, they would get evaluated in the context of: `"$@"`.  Luckily, the double quotes in this case would eliminate most side effects, but it's important to be careful which bash process or sub-shell is evaluating those arguments.

## Unix Output Redirection: `stdin`, `stdout`, & `stderr`

Most Unix [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) shells have a similar method for redirecting the [standard IO streams](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html), `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.  This includes but isn't limited to: POSIX `sh`, Bash, Z Shell `zsh`, Korn Shell `ksh`, C Shell `csh`, Dash `dash`, and others.

For the purposes of the OP's question, we will focus only on Bash because the `/usr/bin/steam` wrapper script begins with the Bash "[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))" line: `#!/bin/bash`.

In Bash, the first 3 file descriptors (`fd`'s) are always defined as follows, indexed starting from zero `0`:

- `stdin` = `fd 0`
- `stdout` = `fd 1`
- `stderr` = `fd 2`

Output from any command can be redirected using the [output redirection operators in Bash (Bash Reference Manual: § 3.6 Redirections)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). A basic introduction to this can be found in this article: [Bash Redirection Fun With Descriptors](https://copyconstruct.medium.com/bash-redirection-fun-with-descriptors-e799ec5a3c16).  For a more intuitive explanation, with visual aids, [see this excellent article (**Highly Recommended!**)](https://catonmat.net/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three).

### Order of Operations (second nuance):

There is subtle order of operations between the:

- [Redirection operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) (`>`, `<`, `>>`, `<<`, `&>`, `&>>`, `X<&Y`, `X>&Y`, `X>|Y`, `X<&Y-`, `X<>Y`, etc...)

... and the:

- [Control operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-control-operator) (`&`, `;`, `\n` / `newline`, `||`, `&&` `;;`, `;&`, `;;&`, `|` `|&`, `(`, `)`).

From the [Bash Reference Manual § 3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections):

> Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to right.
>
> [...SNIP...]
>
> Note that the order of redirections is significant. For example, the command
>
> ```
> ls > dirlist 2>&1
> ```
>
> directs both standard output (file descriptor 1) and standard error (file descriptor 2) to the file dirlist, while the command
>
> ```
> ls 2>&1 > dirlist
> ```
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard error was made a copy of the standard output before the standard output was redirected to dirlist.

Similarly, there is an order of operations for `&` and other control operators.

From the [Bash Reference Manual: 2.4 Lists of Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html):

> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators ‘`;`’, ‘`&`’, ‘`&&`’, or ‘`||`’, and optionally terminated by one of ‘`;`’, ‘`&`’, or a `newline`.
>
> Of these list operators, ‘`&&`’ and ‘`||`’ have equal precedence, followed by ‘`;`’ and ‘`&`’, which have equal precedence.
>
> A sequence of one or more newlines may appear in a `list` to delimit commands, equivalent to a semicolon.

Finally, specifically the section about `&`:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘`&`’, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell. This is known as executing the command in the *background*, and these are referred to as *asynchronous* commands. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is `0` (`true`). When job control is not active (see [Job Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html)), the standard input for asynchronous commands, in the absence of any explicit redirections, is redirected from `/dev/null`.

#### Why the OP's commands didn't do what was expected

The first two commands tried were:

- `steam & > /dev/null 2>/dev/null`
- `steam & > /dev/null 2>&1`

The reason these did not perform the intended redirection of both `stdout` and `stderr` as expected is due to the aforementioned **order of operations / operator precedence** rules listed above.  Specifically, the `&` operator is seen first in left-to-right order.  It gets applied to the first word, the command `steam` and sends it to the background running as an *asynchronous command*.  `stdin` is connected to `/dev/null`, while `stdout`, and `stderr` remain connected to the controlling [Pseudoterminal / `pty`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal).  This is explained further below.

But first...

#### More Chained `exec` Confusion!

We saw that the first `steam` we ran in the command was actually a short wrapper script which ran `exec` on `/usr/lib/steam/steam`.  *However, that happens to be **yet another wrapper script!***

To further confuse things, that wrapper script ***also runs `exec`*** again!

We can verify that this is the case by looking at the process tree and inspecting what's going on:

```bash
# Set -x to turn on bash's trace output
# Run: steam & > /dev/null 2>&1
# Set +x to turn off bash's trace output again

set -x; steam & > /dev/null 2>&1 ; set +x; 
[1] 254855
+ steam
+ set +x

## Note: the "[1] 254855" output above indicates the PID
##       that Bash has spawned in the background as Job #1

# Steam Output still spammed to PTY terminal...
# So, to clarify things, run this in another new terminal:

ps auxww | grep -E 'steam\b'
```

```bash
# Outputs:
exampleuser   254855  0.0  0.0   7908  4420 pts/0    S    15:58   0:00 bash /home/exampleuser/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh
exampleuser   254986  6.4  0.2 1147568 180712 pts/0  S<l  15:58   0:02 /home/exampleuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
exampleuser   255229  0.0  0.0   6580  2544 pts/1    R+   15:58   0:00 grep --colour=auto -E steam\b
```

Looking at the process tree for PID `254855` (`bash`), we can see it was running a script `steam.sh`.  This shell script ran `exec` on the `steam` located in `/usr/lib/steam/steam` (yet **another** shell script).  This second bash script took over the subprocess PID `254986` thanks to the `exec` call in the first wrapper script.  Next, that second `/usr/lib/steam/steam` bash script does a bunch of function defines, setup, and bootstrap steps and finally runs:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[... SNIP ...]

exec "$LAUNCHSTEAMDIR/$STEAMBOOTSTRAP" "$@"
```

Yet **another** `exec` call! This time to a ***third wrapper script***

The next executable which is called by the variable name "`$STEAMBOOTSTRAP`" by that second wrapper script under `/usr/lib/steam/`.

The second wrapper script takes care of Steam's "bootstrap" process, which involves downloading and unpacking a tarball (found on this system under `/usr/lib/steam/bootstraplinux_*.tar.xz`).

Inside that `.tar.xz` archive file is **yet another wrapper script** `steam.sh`, and the real `steam-runtime` compiled libraries and binaries.

```bash
tar -tf  /usr/lib/steam/bootstraplinux_*.tar.xz

# Outputs:

linux32/
linux32/steamerrorreporter
steam.sh
steamdeps.txt
ubuntu12_32/
ubuntu12_32/crashhandler.so
ubuntu12_32/steam
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/COPYING
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/README.txt
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/built-using.txt
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/common-licenses/
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/common-licenses/Apache-2.0
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/common-licenses/Artistic
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/common-licenses/BSD
[... SNIP ...]
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/common-licenses/LGPL-3
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/lib/
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
[... SNIP ...]
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/manifest.txt
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/run.sh
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/scripts/
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/scripts/README.txt
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/scripts/check-program.sh
[... SNIP ...]
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/scripts/fix-symlinks.sh
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/scripts/switch-runtime.sh
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/setup.sh
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6
[... SNIP ...]
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/version.txt
```

As we can see from the above `.tar.xz` file's output, there is a ***third wrapper script*** called `steam.sh`.  It will be placed usually in the user's `$HOME` directory, on this system under: `~/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh`.

The third wrapper script does a lot more defining functions, detecting the host's CPU architecture, Linux distrobution, release version & platform (currently hardcoded to `ubuntu12_32`!), performing another download & bootstrap of that `tar.xz` file processing any possible command line args (e.g. `--reset`, `--run`, etc...), and setting variables including `STEAMEXEPATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, unsetting `LD_PRELOAD`, etc...

Depending on how it's called, that third wrapper script performs ***yet another `exec` call!* ‍**

This final binary is located here:

```
${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
```

```bash
file  ${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam

# Outputs
/home/exampleuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=93a61e82cbc9b50ffc893ef60bc09e2c8a948fab, not stripped
```

So finally, this binary executable is `exec`'d and takes over the third wrapper script's process ID PID `254986`.

We can see the result of all these `exec` calls and wrapper scripts by looking at the process tree it spawned:

```
# Look at PID 254855:

pstree -p 254855

# Outputs:

bash(254855)---steam(254986)-+-steamwebhelper(255001)-+-steamwebhelper(255058)---steamwebhelper(255087)-+-{steamwebhelper}(255103)
                             |                        |                                                 |-{steamwebhelper}(255105)
                             |                        |                                                 |-{steamwebhelper}(255106)
                             |                        |                                                 |-{steamwebhelper}(255107)
                             |                        |                                                 |-{steamwebhelper}(255115)


[... SNIP ...]

                             |                        |                                                 `-{steamwebhelper}(255158)
                             |                        |-steamwebhelper(255059)---steamwebhelper(255068)-+-steamwebhelper(255160)-+-+
                             |                        |                                                 |                        |-+
                             |                        |                                                 |                        |-+

[...SNIP...]

# NOTE: **Many** child subprocesses are started by the real `steam` binary!
```

We can see the results of the attempted redirection by viewing the special `fd` "directory" under the `/proc` interface (fake filesystem created by Linux kernel). This can be done by looking at these process' file descriptors in the [`/proc` interface filesystem](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/proc.html) via the `PID` (Process ID number):

##### For the parent `bash` itself:

```bash
# Remember the process tree: 
#     bash(254855)---steam(254986)-+-steamwebhelper(255001)-+- [... SNIP ...]
ls -l /proc/254855/fd

# Outputs:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:18 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:18 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:18 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:18 255 -> /home/exampleuser/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh
```

Here, we can see that all standard IO file descriptors (`0` / `stdin`, `1` / `stdout`, and `2` / `stderr`) are still mapped to the controlling Pseudoterminal / `/dev/pts/0`.  
Bash also internally mapped file descriptor `255` to the *first* wrapper script.

##### For the real `steam` binary:

```bash
ls -l /proc/254986/fd

# Outputs:

total 0
lrwx------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:30 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:30 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:30 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:30 3 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:30 4 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lr-x------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:30 5 -> /home/exampleuser/.steam/steam.pipe
lr-x------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:30 6 -> /dev/urandom
lrwx------ 1 exampleuser exampleuser 64 Jun 13 16:30 7 -> /home/exampleuser/.local/share/Steam/logs/bootstrap_log.txt

[... SNIP ...]

# NOTE: **Many** other file descriptors with higher numbers are opened by the real steam binary!  These have been omitted for clarity.
```

So the resulting `steam` **binary** process still has all the same mappings as the parent bash shell!  The suffixed `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null` had no effect, and were effectively thrown away by the parsing logic in bash.

Here's what happened:

- The top-level `bash` shell interpreted the line: `steam & > /dev/null 2>&1`
- The command `steam` was parsed (subject to all the usual [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions))
- The command `steam` was found in the shell's `PATH`, and evaluated to mean: `/usr/bin/steam` (The wrapper shell script that Valve provided and described above)
- The `&` control operator was found, thus `bash` will place the command into the background as an *asynchronous command*

  - The `exec` chain of `steam` wrapper scripts and `steam` binary happens here.
  - As per the [POSIX `exec` command definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/exec.html), each `exec` call replaced the shell with command without creating a new process.
  - Any arguments passed via `"$@"` are passed to the final `steam` command.
  - Any redirections passed here would affect the current shell execution environment. (**N/A** in our case)
- Bash continues parsing & executing the command line, having placed the original `steam` PID into the background.

  - The `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null` string is parsed as a new command (as if it were intended to be a list of commands specified by a newline or `;` character preceding it)

    - The `''` empty string is implied in front of the redirect operators `>` and `2>`, therefore redirecting the output of nothing.  (**Note:** This is subtly different than a  [`noop` / `:`](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#COLON0REF), which can be used to truncate a file as in: `: >/file-to-truncate.log`).
    - The `> /dev/null` is found and we usually expect it to redirect `stdout` / `fd 1` to `/dev/null`.  However, here in the context of `''` empty string as command, it does nothing.
    - The `2>/dev/null` is found and we expect it to usually redirect `stderr` / `fd 2` to `/dev/null`.  Yet, again the context being the parent `bash` process which your original terminal is running on and having `''` empty string as a command... it does nothing.

So, because `&` took precedence, those other trailing redirect operators `>/dev/null 2>&1` are eaten by the shell and have no effect.  We can see this is the case by running the following:

```bash
set -x; >/dev/null 2>&1 ; set +x; 

# Outputs
+ set +x
```

So, the only command seen by `bash` after `set -x` is the final `set +x` to turn off trace output, as the above demonstrates.